# Continuous time Markov chain, expectation of transitions in an interval

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, expected-value

For a continuous time markov chain we have these assumptions and definitions:

> **Assumption 1**: We assume that for any states i and j and any times t
>   and t+s where $s\ge 0$, the conditional probability
>   $P(Y(t+s)=j|Y(t)=i)$ is well-defined in the sense that its value does
>   not depend on any information about the process before time t.
>
> **Assumption 2**: We assume that for any positive time interval h:
>
> P(Two or more transitions within a time period of length h)=o(h).
>
> That a function $f$ is $o(h)$ means that $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow
>  0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=0$.
>
> **Definition 1:**
>
> $_tp_x^{ij}=P(Y(x+t=j)|Y(x)=i)$
>
> **Definition 2:**
>
> $\mu_x^{ij}=\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{_hp_x^{ij}}{h}$ for
>    $i\ne j$.
>
> **Assumption 3:** For all states i and j and all $x \ge 0$ , we
>   assume that $_tp_x^{ij}$ is a differentiable function in t.
>
> **Lemma 1**: $_hp_x^{ij}=\mu_x^{i,j}h+o(h)$. Proof: Omitted

Assume that you at time x start at state i. A book that I am reading says that the expectation of the number of jumps in an interval $[x+t,x+t+\Delta t]$ from state j to k is:

$_tp_x^{ij}\cdot \mu_{x+t}^{jk}\Delta t+o(\Delta t)$.

Can someone please explain why this is the case? Why do we have $o(\Delta t)$?

The reason I am wondering is that this quanity must be:

$\sum\limits_{l=2}^{l=\infty}l\cdot P(\text{l transitions from j to k in the interval})$.

I don't see why this quantity is $o(\Delta t)$? The probabilities are $o(\Delta t)$ sure, but we must multiply them with $l$, and there is even the possibility of an infinite amount of transitions in the interval, and then the quantity becomes infinity? We also have the problem that there is a countable, not finite, amount of $o(\Delta t)$-functions.

Can you please help me?

Comment: The case where there are an infinite amount of transitions in finite time is known as *explosion*, and is a pathological case that generally can be ignored.

Comment: @Math1000 I see, thank you. But can it be proved that the probability of an explosion is zero on an interval, because then we can use that $0\cdot\infty=0$? Or maybe that when the interval becomes small enough it is zero? But even if that is solved we still have the problem that there are a countable number of little-oh functions, do you see how to solve that?